# How to set up a stateful firewall on an am335x Starter Kit board?

Tags: iptables, firewall, arm

In the past, I have used the following script to set up a stateful firewall (on a normal x64 Ubuntu machine) without issue:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -N TCP
iptables -N UDP
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i wlan0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j UDP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j TCP
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-rst
iptables -A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-proto-unreachable
iptables -A TCP -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

I am trying to accomplish the same on an am335x Starter Kit board, running the standard SDK 6 image. As such it runs TI's Arago OS.

It fails on the lines involving '-m conntrack' with:

```
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

The output of 'iptables -S' is:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

I tried 'modprobe nf_conntrack' to no avail (the command succeeded, but did not help.)
I also tried purposefully misspelling parts of the command such as:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate BLAH -j ACCEPT
```

gives error: iptables v1.4.15: Bad ctstate "BLAH"

And:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED -j BLAH
```

gives error: iptables v1.4.15: Couldn't load target `BLAH':No such file or directory

So curiously, it seems to indicate it is complaining about the '-A INPUT' portion, which works perfectly fine in other commands such as:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had posted this question to the TI Forums as well, and got a [response](http://e2e.ti.com/support/wireless_connectivity/f/307/t/371814.aspx).

Enabling CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNTRACK in the kernel config solved this issue.
I just set CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNTRACK=y in the config, rebuilt with the SDK (instructions [here](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/AMSDK_Linux_User%27s_Guide)).

After installing the new kernel and modules, the -m conntrack command doesn't complain anymore.